# Facebook Connect Logout works fine in localhost but not on server

Tags: c#, facebook

I have implemented facebook connect application in one of my website.

Everything works fine but logout does not.

I have used:

```
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function FB_Logout() {
         FB.Connect.logout();
    }
</script>
```

and the link:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="hyljslogout" CausesValidation="false" PostBackUrl="~/Default.aspx?action=logout" runat="server" Text="Logout" OnClientClick="FB_Logout();" ForeColor="#088498" Visible="false" />
```

This code works fine in localhost but in server it logs out of facebook but the cookies still remains in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [Legacy JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/) and as it states in that page:

> We have deprecated this version of the JavaScript SDK. We recommend
>   all developers switch to our new, improved [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

I'm not sure why it does not work for you on the servers but does on localhost, but using the deprecated sdk can result in unexpected behavior.
Try using the new sdk, the "how to" is explained in the documentation, once you load it you can then [logout](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/) like this:

```
function FB_Logout() {
    FB.logout(function(response) {
        ....
    });
}
```